# How to make a dict from an enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make a dict from an enum?

```
from enum import Enum
class Shake(Enum):
    VANILLA = "vanilla"
    CHOCOLATE = "choc"
    COOKIES = "cookie"
    MINT = "mint"

dct = {}
for i in Shake:
    dct[i]=i.value

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{<Shake.VANILLA: 'vanilla'>: 'vanilla', <Shake.CHOCOLATE: 'choc'>: 'choc', <Shake.COOKIES: 'cookie'>: 'cookie', <Shake.MINT: 'mint'>: 'mint'}
```

But I want the key to be VANILLA and not `<Shake.VANILLA: 'vanilla'>`

Comment: your variable name for your dictionary is `dct` but in your for loop you are refering to `dict[i]`.  try `dct[i]=dct[i].value`

Comment: That still won't make sense, though, because if `dct` is empty then there is no `dct[i]` to get a value from.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can just use a dictionary comprehension

```py
from enum import Enum
class Shake(Enum):
    VANILLA = "vanilla"
    CHOCOLATE = "choc"
    COOKIES = "cookie"
    MINT = "mint"

dct = {i.name: i.value for i in Shake}
print(dct)
```

**OUTPUT**

`{'VANILLA': 'vanilla', 'CHOCOLATE': 'choc', 'COOKIES': 'cookie', 'MINT': 'mint'}`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Don't do this, read the comments below

You can make use of `map`, like so

```
from enum import Enum
class Shake(Enum):
    VANILLA = "vanilla"
    CHOCOLATE = "choc"
    COOKIES = "cookie"
    MINT = "mint"

dct = dict(map(lambda item: (item.name, item.value), Shake))
```

Comment: Why is this better than a dict comprehension?

Comment: It's clearly not. I just didn't know you can iterate over Enum(s) :)

Comment: Well, `map` works by iterating over the enum, too - in general, if you can `map` something then you can iterate over it.